# GeoLocation issues?

Tags: android, geolocation, locationmanager, locationlistener

How can I change the `LocationManager` to get just one location? The app keeps updating the location.

```
public void onClick(View view) 
     //this make the app keep update
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0, listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first approach would be to use locationManager.requestSingleUpdate() instead of locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()

OR

the second solution is to unregister the listener immediately after you received the first update, as follows:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    // do something with the received location 
}
```